# Cell constraints won't be active until I scroll content off the screen - automatic dimension Table view - Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` that uses cell content constraints in order to auto generate cell heights using `UITableView.automaticDimension`.

Here is a bit of code from my `UIViewController` (I pasted most important methods only):

```
     lazy var tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: .grouped)

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
                    
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 112
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        
        tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 50
        
        tableView.register(TransactionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: TransactionCell.reuseId)
        tableView.register(TransactionsHeaderView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: TransactionsHeaderView.reuseId)
        
        tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        // <--> setting up my data here... <-->

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TransactionCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as? TransactionCell  else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TableViewCell.")
        }
        
        cell.transaction = sections[indexPath.section].transactions[indexPath.row]
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

Then I have my custom `UITableViewCell` class:

```
    lazy var backgroundBox = RoundShadowView()
    lazy var cellView = TransactionCellView()
    lazy var detailView = TransactionCellDetailView()

    private func commonInit() {
        
        selectionStyle = .none
        
        backgroundColor = .clear
        contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        backgroundBox.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        backgroundBox.shouldRasterize = false
        backgroundBox.insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: SAFE_AREA_MARGIN, bottom: 15, right: SAFE_AREA_MARGIN)
        
        detailView.alpha = 0
        detailView.addTopBorder()
        
        backgroundBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cellView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        detailView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                
        contentView.addSubview(backgroundBox)
        backgroundBox.addSubview(cellView)
        backgroundBox.addSubview(detailView)
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()

        print(#function)
                
        backgroundBox.snp.remakeConstraints { make in
            make.left.equalToSuperview()
            make.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalToSuperview().priority(999)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(111).priority(999)
        }
        
        cellView.snp.remakeConstraints { make in
            make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(SAFE_AREA_MARGIN)
            make.right.equalToSuperview().inset(SAFE_AREA_MARGIN)
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(15)
            make.height.equalTo(111)
        }

        detailView.snp.remakeConstraints { make in
            make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(SAFE_AREA_MARGIN)
            make.right.equalToSuperview().inset(SAFE_AREA_MARGIN)
            make.top.equalTo(cellView.snp.bottom)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
    }
```

I'm using `SnapKit` library to make constraints.

As you can see I set top, bottom and height constraints to force the `UITableViewCell` to increase its height.

The issue is that when I build and run, my views layouts are set but cells heights aren't calculated yet.
However if I scroll until a cell is not visible and I scroll back down, its height is calculated following my constraints.
How can cells height be calculated the first time?

Comment: You can see me puzzling over this here: https://www.biteinteractive.com/adventures-in-ios-programming-self-sizing-cells/

Comment: @matt But shouldn't he be setting the constraints right after adding the subviews?

Comment: @Desdenova, You right, adding setNeedsUpdateConstraints() right after adding subviews works. But it is strange tho.

Answer (score 1):

As @Desdenova said, adding `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` right after adding subviews solved my issue.